# performance problem when dealing with DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, dataset

Alright, so I'm having a problem with performance when I'm manipulating the data in the dataframe, So let me explain my problem along with my approach. Basically, I have a dataset with 200 rows and 3 columns in a dataframe, each column can accept 1 out of multiple possible values. Now I want to construct a new dataframe where I attach every ID in the original dataset with every possible value of the 3 columns. Then, I want to add a new column that has different values as the following: for every row in the new dataframe I will check the original dataset, if this row exists there (this ID has this value) then I will put some value, otherwise, I will put another value. That's the formulation of my problem and I hope it is clear. Now here is my approach to performing this:

```py
for i in dataset['ID']:
    for j in dataset:
        if j != 'ID':
            if  j=='col1':
                key = dataset.iloc[i-1][j]
                new_dataset = new_dataset.append({'ID' :str(i), 'col_val' 
                :str(key), 'value' :x},  
                ignore_index = True)

                for d in col1_unique:
                    if str(d) != str(key):
                        new_dataset = new_dataset .append({'ID' :str(i), 
                        'col_val' :d, 'value' :y},  
                        ignore_index = True) 
            
            elif  j=='col2':
                key = dataset.iloc[i-1][j]
                new_dataset = new_dataset .append({'ID' :str(i), 'col_val' :key, 
                'value' :x},  
                    ignore_index = True)
                
                for d in col2_unique:
                    if str(d) != str(key):
                        new_dataset = new_dataset .append({'ID' :str(i), 
                        'col_val' :d, 'value' :y},  
                            ignore_index = True)

            else:
                key = dataset.iloc[i-1][j]
                new_dataset = new_dataset .append({'ID' :str(i), 'col_val' :key, 
                'vlue' :x},  
                    ignore_index = True)

                for d in col3_unique:
                    if str(d) != str(key):
                        new_dataset = new_dataset.append({'ID' :str(i), 
                        'col_val' :d, 'value' :y},  
                        ignore_index = True)
```

Now, this is working as it meant to be, but the problem is the low performance. For a small dataset (such as the 200 rows) it maybe fast, but for larger datasets it can take up to 5 minutes. I tried different approaches to enhance the performance, such as reading it row by row and accessing the values from that row instead of calling it from the whole dataset, but this didn't enhance much as well. Therefore, you are welcome to share any ideas to increase the performance.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: kindly provide sample dataframe with expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do not call `append` iteratively on a dataframe**: this is very inefficient since it create a whole new dataframe for each new row added, causing a `O(n**2)` appending.

Moreover, you can **factorize the code so that expressions are not recomputed again and again**. Indeed, the Python interpreter is not very smart and it does not optimize that for you.

Here is the resulting code that should be significantly faster:

```py
import pandas as pd

newDf_IDs = []
newDf_colVals = []
newDf_values = []

for i in dataset['ID']:
    iStr = str(i)
    for j in dataset:
        if j != 'ID':
            key = dataset.iloc[i-1][j]
            keyStr = str(key)

            if  j=='col1':
                newDf_IDs.append(iStr)
                newDf_colVals.append(keyStr)
                newDf_values.append(x)
                uniqueCol = col1_unique
            elif  j=='col2':
                newDf_IDs.append(iStr)
                newDf_colVals.append(key)
                newDf_values.append(x)
                uniqueCol = col2_unique
            else:
                newDf_IDs.append(iStr)
                newDf_colVals.append(key)
                newDf_values.append(x)
                uniqueCol = col3_unique

            for d in uniqueCol:
                if str(d) != keyStr:
                    newDf_IDs.append(iStr)
                    newDf_colVals.append(d)
                    newDf_values.append(y)

new_dataset = pd.DataFrame({'ID': newDf_IDs, 'col_val': newDf_colVals, 'value': newDf_values})
```

PS: note that I fixed a typo `vlue` and this code is an untested prototype.

Comment: Yes, I actually tried something similar and append my data in an extra dict instead of calling append on the dataframe every time. This improved the performance a lot since the running time decreased from 5 minutes to 4 seconds!!
Thank you very much

Comment: Dealing with dataframe can be triky, for example some index operations can be very slow. I suggest to "divide and conquer"  your problem in order to identify exaclty *where* the bottleneck are. You can try to use perf_tool to divide the code in chunks and see what's happen on each.